# I've lost my wife using wait command in the woods how can i find her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I married the huntress woman(companions) and we were going somewhere and I told her to wait and then I forgot to get her and now I have no clue where to find her.

I looked at the companions place, my houses I have 4 and no where to be found

its on x-box 360

Comment: Maybe it's time to start dating again.

Comment: i cant it wont let me........#aloneforever

Comment: After waiting for roughly 3-7 days, companions set to wait for you return to wherever they return to when you dismiss them.

Answer (score 3):

Followers will eventually return to wherever their default location is. If you wait a few in-game days, Aela will either go back to wherever you two moved (this is only applicable if you own an in-game house and specified that she make her home there), or to Jorrvaskr.